# Divide numbers into fewest groups with each group's sum bounded

Tags: algorithms

We have an integer $K$ and an array of $N$ positive integers each smaller than $K$. How do we group the numbers into the minimum number of groups where the sum of each group is less than or equal to $K$?

Comment: This is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments suggested it is called the Bin Packing Problem.